# Facing issue with ajax with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have registration.php page with email and password which call's a function on submit
            i.e

```
         the function ChkVal() is written in comman.js file i.e

        function ChkVal()
        {
               var Valid = true;
               var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
               var address = document.getElementById("Email").value;
               if(reg.test(address) == false) 
               {
       ////somecode to check if it is valid email id or not
                }
               else
               {


    this is the section where i have the problem 

                   $(function() {

                          $.ajax({
                                url  : 'RegCheck.php',
                                type : 'POST',
                                data : 'User=' + address,
                                success : function(result){
                                   if(result != "No")
                                   {
                                       document.getElementById("EmailChk").innerHTML = result;   
///the result return from RegCheck.php will be Either already exist or No


                                       Valid = false;
                                   }
                                }

                          });              


                   });                         
                  document.getElementById("MailMand").innerHTML = "" ;

               }
```

if i put alert message here then no issue  or downward any where before return Valid but if i remove alert message then query insert data into database...

```
               return Valid;

        };
```

Comment: Your request is asynchronous, then the valid value is not set immediatly. Additionnaly your code is not correctly designed. You are using jquery , then why not use the validate plugin ? Example http://alittlecode.com/files/jQuery-Validate-Demo/

Comment: registration  with email and password ????

Comment: And use $("EmailChk").html(...); now you have jQuery anyway

Comment: sorry guys i am not expert like you are as i have just started learning jquery but thanks anyway for your reply

Comment: whats your exact problem. could you explain it please? what is the output you are looking for?

Comment: i have a function called Checkdata in a *.js file as show above to check whether email exist or not in the database now when i keep alert message before return Valid; i recieve result from ajax as already exist and display message in label 'EmailChk' which is true but as soon as i remove the alert message, before getting my result the query for insert is fired and even if email exist .i have spend two days doing this but not getting solution. thank you

Answer (score 2):

you have to study more about **jquery ajax**.
The response from the ajax should be in `html` form. You could please `alert` it on the `success` block, then you can understand the problems.
Just try like this.

```
else
{
   $.ajax({
             url  : 'RegCheck.php',
             type : 'POST',
             data : {User: address},
                    success : function(result){
                       alert(result);
                       if(result != "No")
                       {
                         document.getElementById("EmailChk").innerHTML = result;                      Valid = false;
                       }
                    }

               });              



}
```

Comment: i dont want to the alert message to popup rather i want the result to be showed in label tag $('#EmailChk').append(result); if result is not equal to NO and if the result is equal to NO then insert it into database

Comment: I don't mean that. i added the alert to check the response from the `ajax`. do yo edited the `data` as i showed. this is the proper way to pass variables through `ajax` request.